# AChartengine: 1. repaint(), 2. limit data points

Tags: android, achartengine

1:
I use achartengine to draw a line chart. Since i receive constantly data i want the chart scroll automatically to the right. My Problem is now, that the chart only scrolls when i touch the display of my phone(Android 2.3). Chart is running in extra thread and gets repaint() every ~100 ms.

2: How do i limit the collected data points. Is there an option to save the last 100 points and delete the older values? Currently my app saves all data points and gets slower and slower.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can dynamically set the visible chart area using: `renderer.setXAxisMin()` and `renderer.setXAxisMax()`. Call `repaint()` after calling these methods.
2. Using the same APIs as the above you can control which data to be displayed. It's up to you to remove data from the series after that.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't have repaint() right after setting the axes dimensions. Now it works.